# Why is numpy.loadtxt() / numpy.genfromtxt() truncating this row, mid-column, after a space character?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy
with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
    print(np.loadtxt(csv_file, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', dtype=str, usecols=np.arange(64, 95)))
```

There are definitely two rows of 95 columns in `my_file.csv` but I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PETERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scp07870\var\www\html\iii\ac\paint\color.py", line 84, in <module>
    print(np.loadtxt(csv_file, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', usecols=np.arange(64, 95), dtype=str))
  File "C:\Users\Peter Griffin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1139, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "C:\Users\Peter Griffin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1060, in read_data
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
  File "C:\Users\Peter Griffin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1060, in <listcomp>
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I remove the column specifier, no exceptions raise.

```
import numpy
with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
    print(np.loadtxt(csv_file, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', dtype=str))
```

However, the row falls way short of its 95 columns. Output:

```
['2020-06-28T00:41:45.383Z' '42.9-96.9-49.2' '' '' '' '' '42.9-96.9-49.2; ']
```

Upon manual inspection of the file, the 7th column of the 2nd row has value `42.9-96.9-49.2; #D90100` which includes the only space character in the file.

I'm specifically looking for a solution to this issue—not an alternative or a workaround (I previously had no trouble parsing the file using the `csv` library)—for curiosity's sake if nothing else.

Comment: '#' is the comment character; everything after that is ignored.  There's a parameter to change how comments are handled.